# Conectar Function App de Azure a VPN para usar FTP

Tags: c#, azure, ftp, vpn

Estoy intentando hacer una conexión a una VPN externa desde Azure para poder usarla dentro de un Function App. En concreto lo que preciso es desde una función de Azure conectarme a un FTP a traves de una VPN (¿Sería posible OpenVPN?). La cuestión es que no se si existe alguna forma de hacerlo sin tener la necesidad de crear la red virtual, gateway, red local, etc. que he visto en la documentación. 
En caso de que no exista alternativa me surge la duda de si es compatible hacerlo con OpenVPN. 
Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 1):

Desde un Azure Function no puede definir temas de infraestructura como es la conexion a una VPN, recuerda que este ejecuta cuando se lo invoca por un evento ya sea un timer o una invocacion http, etc, no estaria bueno iniciar y cerrar una conxion VPN en cada llamada

La VPN de estar establecida previamente

[Integrate a function app with an Azure virtual network](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La `VNet` debe estar previamente configurada para poder tener acceso desde el codigo de la Azure Function